# 2-stage BJT CC-EC amplifier

Tags: amplifier, bjt, npn, frequency-response

Using proteus I designed this amplifier:
[image: CC-EC]

But I got this result:
[image: V out]

I don't know what is the problem in my design. I've been changing the values of the linking capacitors but didn't get any result.

Comment: "But" does not make sense. You simulated something _and_ got a result. You need to provide details what behavior you expected.

Comment: Did the current answer really solve your problem? If not, you shouldn't just accept any first answer that arrives.

Comment: I just wanted to get a bigger signal amplitude as an output and a complete signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  1st stage collector output is a current sink driving a small pullup R shunted by CC load such that the cap attenuates the voltage gain above 1/RC.  So you have a mismatch.  **Move the CC cap. to the emitter.**

The 2nd stage emitter output is shorted the CE cap such that it attenuates the signal to a flat line. **Remove CE.**

1st look at R ratios for DC bias , then impedance ratios for AC gain then loading ratios between stages. Then look at large signal clipping and Power dissipation and make adjustments.

Comment: So how we can design this amplifier for maximum power transfer ? First stage EC and second stage CC ? Or 2 EC?

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-976-high-speed-communication-circuits-and-systems-spring-2003/lecture-notes/guest3.pdf